# Vector reference c++

Tags: c++

I want to use a reference to vector passed in as a parameter. How can I do that ?

```
static void sort(polygon2D& poly) {
    vector<point2D> t = poly.m_vPoint2D;

    /* the rest doesn't matter */
}
```

Comment: `vector<point2D>& t = poy.m_vPoint2D;`?

Comment: Just use the `&` operator? `vector<point2D>& t = poly.m_vPOint2D;

Comment: There is no such thing as a variable to reference. Before you go exploring, try searching and understanding basic concepts. It will save you some time later on, and help you think "programmatically".

Comment: Thanks ! The solution was `std::vector<point2D> &t`

Comment: Thanks for your question!  While we welcome questions at every level, please check out [ask].  In particular, we need to know what you've done to try to solve your own problem, and also, your example code should be as minimal as possible to demonstrate the problem.  I went ahead and helped you out with that this time.

Comment: @vikramls Note that `&` is not actually an operator in this context. It *is* an operator when it's used to take the address of something, but not when being used to declare a reference.

Comment: @cdhowie, yes you are correct - I should not have used the word operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you go about creating a reference:

```
vector<point2D>& t = poly.m_vPoint2D; // here
const int n = (int) t.size(); // Call size() on the reference you have
```

Comment: That's a different question altogether - why not use `std::sort` with your own sort function instead of using `std::swap`?

Comment: This is part of an exercise that I am making for the university. But std::sort is more powerfull and easy to use :)